# Cetain google calendar events not importing C#

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I have built a Calendar application that has the ability to import Google Calendar events.
On certain occasions, the event's are returned perfectly. However, some events do not return at all. I cannot narrow down the reason for what might be causing these issues.

Sometimes it's on certain Google 'calendars' and I thought it may be due to security prevention on these particular calendars but I can not find a way to bypass these issues.

This is my code:

```
var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    new ClientSecrets
    {
        ClientId = "id",
        ClientSecret = "secret",
    },
    new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
    accountEmail,
    CancellationToken.None).Result;

var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "appname",
});

EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List(calendarid);

Events events = request.Execute();

foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(eventItem.Summary);
}
```

It won't import all this data from a calendar called 'Supplier confirmed dates'

[image]

But it will import the data from this calendar called 'Trade's diary'

[image]

But with another calendar, it will import some events and not others which is why I am confused.

Any suggestions will be welcomed, please.

Comment: Your code is just *listing* the events - if the problem is with listing, then I suggest you remove all mention of importing. If that's *not* the problem, please clarify. What's happening with the events that aren't working? Basically, the more detail you can provide, the better...

Comment: Sorry I cut parts of the code out for simplicity for the question but normally rather than writing to the console it would read the event items attributes into a database table which then will be outputted via a datagridview. However, some events are displaying when I output to the console but not all of them and I am not sure why specific events are being read while others aren't. If you notice on the screen shot 'Rocal', this is being read fine but 'DAWS' is not.

Comment: Right, so I would suggest editing your question to clarify that it's about "some events not being returned when listing them". I would also suggest looking carefully at the options in https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list - I wonder whether this is something to do with repeated events and whether or not they're expanded.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help. It was because I had more than 250 results and I didn't realize that there was a limit on how many events the calendar returns so it was outputting the first 250 and then stopping. All sorted now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### By default [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) shows maximum 250 results per page

- For the calendar where the request `won't import all this data` it looks like there might be more than 250 events present and thus, not all of them will be retrieved
- In this case you can either

  - set `maxResults` to a higher value - up to 2500
  - or retrieve the next page by setting `pageToken` to the value of `nextPageToken` you obtained in the [response](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list?apix_params=%7B%22calendarId%22%3A%22primary%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22*%22%7D#response) of your first query

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't realized that there was a limit on the number of results that can be returned from the Google calendar. Since my calendar had more than the limit of '250' it was returning the first '250' then stopping so I upped this limit to '2500' (the maximum it can return) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: This is not an answer. You should put this as an edit to your question or a comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: @Karel: I read it as a recap of the accepted answer and an "It works now"-comment. It brings nothing to the table that the accepted answer hasn't already brought.

Comment: @PalleDue I actually posted this answer a couple of minutes before the accepted answer but was unable to 'accept' my own post as the answer since it has not been over 2 days. So I decided to accept the other answer 'ziganotschka' provided as it was similar to my own response.

Comment: Sorry, I'll rest my case.